# With Media Queries is there a "everything else" kind of thing?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

** Amateur warning **

I'd like to  have four settings for my CSS, and I'd like the last one to be a "everything else" kind of media query, is there such a thing???

These are my first three queries:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (min-height: 940px) /* for large displays */
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px) and (min-height:689px) and (max-height:939px) /* for smaller displays */
@media only screen and (max-width:1024px) and (max-height:900px) /* for ipad n the like */
```

Now I'd like one to respond to anything else I might have left out... I hope I make sense...

Comment: have you tried making the css file cater for everything and conditionally adjust for those 3 media queries specifically?

Comment: as a matter of fact you already have 2 "everything else": your first line will cover everything OVER 1024px width, and your 3rd line will cover everything UNDER 1024px width

Comment: @jamesgiang yes-- this "fourth" option just takes over all the other queries

Comment: @Fabio I'd hope so, but when I play w my window size it messes up...

Answer (score 7):

```
.class { 
    //this is everything else
}

@media (max-width:768px) { //or whatever px you're using
    .class{
        //styling for .class on mobile
    }
}
```

Anything that has `class="class"` will get the first (non-media query) `.class` styling.  Anything that falls within your media query pixel definition will get the media query styling (second `.class` in this example).

Side note: I have used media queries with bootstrap and I have not come across height media queries, in my experience it is done with width only.  I am not sure if there is added value in doing height, maybe it allows you to get very specific, but for me that would be too much to manage.

Comment: thnx for the +1... I'm not so sure I could apply what you say about the .class, and thnks 4 the advice on the height property...

Comment: Height could be used to determine that the monitor is in portrait mode if you want a different layout in that case